# Multi layer loss tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

I am trying to build a multi layer loss
I am using AlexNet as my base network and I have 4 classes that have 3 possible labels, so I tried to build it as follow:

```
output_gt = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [None,4,3], name='output')
```

this is not my real output but this is his size,meaning the output layer on the alexNet is of size [4,3]
I want to be able to view only the output that is relevant to the class I put as an input.so in the end for each image i will get [1,3] size output that came from the relevant  part of  the original output
for example

```
batch_size =2
labels = [0,2]
output = [*batc_size_dim*][[0 0 0], [1 1 1],[2 2 2 ],[3 3 3]]
```

i will get

```
new_output = [[0 0 0],[2 2 2 ]]
```

how can I use the labels and the output to get new_output
I tried to use mask and I failed
can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

Please try following:
`tf.gather(output, input)`